# Как корректно посчитать длину интового массива, переданного функции?

Tags: c, массивы, функции

Передаю в функцию интовый массив указателем, функция getsize выводит что то непонятное.

```
int get_max_number_of_zeros(int * int_array){

  int lenth = (int)( sizeof(*int_array+6)  /*sizeof(int_array[0])*/ );

  printf("lenth is :%d\n", lenth);

  int max_avalible;
  int max=0;

  for (int i = 0; i <= lenth; i++) {
    if (int_array[i] > 0 ){
      max++;
    }else if(int_array[i]==0&&max_avalible<max){
      max_avalible = max;
      max = 0;
    }
  }

  return max_avalible;

}


   void main() {
      int array[] = {5,4,3,0,3,2,4,1,3,0,-3,-3,-2,-2,-3,4,2,0,-3,-3,0};
      int *arr=array;
      printf("%d\n",get_max_number_of_zeros(array) );
    }
```

P.S и да сама функция вообще выводит рандомные цифры каждый раз.

Answer (score 3):

Ну так у вас `length` - просто размер `int` - обычно 4.

В С нет никакой возможности узнать размер массива, переданного в функцию. Передавайте вместе с ним его длину...

```
int get_max_number_of_zeros(int * int_array, int length)
{
...


int array[] = {5,4,3,0,3,2,4,1,3,0,-3,-3,-2,-2,-3,4,2,0,-3,-3,0};
printf("%d\n",get_max_number_of_zeros(array, sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0])));
```

Кстати:

Неинициализированная переменная: `int max_avalible;`
Выход за границы массива: `for (int i = 0; i <= lenth; i++)`

Comment: Это гениально, спасибо, уже 2 день пытаюсь реализовать ^_^.

Answer (score 3):

Никак не посчитать. После того, как массив превратился в указатель на элемент массива, языковых средств для определения его размера не существует.

Это ваша задача - позаботиться о том, чтобы функция могла как-то получить этот размер. Передавайте его снаружи либо явным образом (отдельный параметр), либо неявным образом (значение-терминатор последним элементом массива).