# Узнать размер массива c++

Tags: c++, массивы, шаблоны-с++

Никак не могу получить верные данные, в общем смысл такой, что функция должна принимать массив, тип данных массива может быть любым, поэтому я использовал шаблонную функцию, и внутри функции мне надо узнать его размер. Я знаю что есть код:

```
int arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
int size = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(*arr);
```

и он выдаст правильный размер, вот только не знаю по какой причине внутри функции он не работает должным образом, при использовании внутри `main()` он работает правильно, но если мы передаем в функцию массив, такой способ работает неправильно.
Я попробовал передавать массив по-разному, в общем не нашел способа, так что прошу помощи.
Как мне передать в шаблонную функцию массив и внутри узнать его размер?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как корректно посчитать длину интового массива, переданного функции?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/949386/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%80%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%83-%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8)

Comment: @Harry, не дубликат же? Там указатель, а тут массив и для него размер добыть можно.

Comment: @Qwertiy Из его вопроса: *вот только не знаю **по какой причине в внутри функции он не работает** должным образом, при использование внутри int main() он работает правильно, но **если мы передаем в функцию массив**, такой способ работает не правильно.*

Comment: @Harry, ну так если передать так, как я передал, то работать будет.

Comment: @Qwertiy Да что мне, жалко, что ли? :) Переоткрыл. Но мнения не изменил...

Comment: @Harry, восстановил коммент про возможный дубликат чтоб ссылка была. На мой взгляд, вопросы связанные, но всё-таки разные.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[tio.run](https://tio.run/##TY7dasMwDIXv/RSHDhoHsrCf9qbJCnuH3pUyFMcphsQ2/hntSp89s1MYQyAh6Ts6EtY@n4WY5yelxRh7iVYZH5ykac9Y9EqfoWmS3pKQ8KFvGAtysiOFhIarlXmLQwWvfuRXgN7j26geAz@Ar6k86lPJbgwQJga0LVafztEVZlgUWOWZzqnYFU3iBuPAKQaD9QU7UPmnLFKkcmn@XZO6Hxt2Z0zpgImU5g@33NLxhA/cXiu8VXivsKmwvWdxb2I3SnSPfZ2AOhF1QupNAvITnMrlGd6Vy8DJEJ3GS/Ka518)

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <typename T, size_t n> void f(T (&a)[n])
{
  cout << "Array of size " << n << ':';
  for (auto &x : a) cout << ' ' << x;
  cout << endl;
}

int main()
{
  int a[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
  double b[] = {.1, .2, .3, .4};

  f(a);
  f(b);

  return 0;
}
```

```
Array of size 5: 1 2 3 4 5
Array of size 4: 0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4
```

PS: Естественно, с указателями не работает.

Comment: И для каждого массива нового размера будет сгенерен  новый код. С такими подходами скоро кремний для чипов DDR закончится -)

Comment: @avp, а отпимизатор не разберётся?

Comment: Не знаю. А что он может сделать? Передать `n` как параметр?    Впрочем, проверьте в т.ч. для разных единиц трансляции

Comment: @avp, не знаю. Но если функция мелкая типа моей, с большой вероятностью он её и так инлайнить будет. А вот если там что-то большое... Но ведь майкросовт использует подобную сигнатуру для gets_s, так что вряд ли она сильно накладная?

Comment: Там под копотом наверняка вызывается обычная библиотечная fgets в которую передается размер буфера. Понятно, что обвязка (из раскрытия шаблона) почти ничего не весит.